# No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/1/s/portal/test-result.xml'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, mocha.js

I am trying to setup task [PublishTestResults@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results) so it shows xunit style mocha test results in [azure devlops pipeline test tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops).

Unfortunately I am getting an error:

```
Obtained XUnit Test Run Start Date: 2020-09-18T12:48:36.0000000Z and Completed Date: 2020-09-18T12:48:36.0470000Z
No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/1/s/portal/test-result.xml'.
Async Command Start: Publish test results
Async Command End: Publish test results
Finishing: Publish Test Results
```

Is there something wrong with the configuration? Perhaps I am missing some additional things.

I was using **mocha-junit-reporter** before but some reason it couldn't display all of the tests cases inside xml file. It only displayed 112 test cases out of 1800+.

Here's the configuration

**package.json**

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:pipeline": "mocha --reporter mocha-xunit-reporter --reporter-options \"addTags=true,assemblyName=Tests,mochaFile=./test-result.xml\" --require test-setup.js --recursive ./ClientApp/**/*.spec.ts*",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mocha": "6.2.0",
    "mocha-xunit-reporter": "2.2.0",
  }
}
```

**yaml file**

```yaml
- job: build_web
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Restore NPM packages'
    inputs:
      command: 'install'
      workingDir: './portal'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: './portal'
      customCommand: 'run test:pipeline'

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
    inputs:
      testRunTitle: 'Mocha Tests'
      testResultsFormat: 'xUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
```

Thanks for help

--Edit

`Run Unit Tests` step was creating the file, if it couldn't find it I would receive an error:

```
##[warning]No test result files matching **/test-*.xml were found.
```

That happened when I was fiddling with a yaml.

**Logs of the step.**

```
Starting: Run Unit Tests
==============================================================================
Task         : npm
Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
Version      : 1.175.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
==============================================================================
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
/usr/local/bin/npm --version
6.14.8
/usr/local/bin/npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.8 node/v12.18.3 linux x64"

; environment configs
userconfig = "/home/vsts/work/1/npm/722.npmrc"

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; cwd = /home/vsts/work/1/s/portal
; HOME = /home/vsts
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

/usr/local/bin/npm run test:pipeline

> portal@1.0.0 test:pipeline /home/vsts/work/1/s/portal
> mocha --reporter mocha-xunit-reporter --reporter-options "addTags=true,assemblyName=Portal Tests,mochaFile=test-result.xml" --require test-setup.js --recursive ./ClientApp/**/*.spec.ts*

Finishing: Run Unit Tests
```

Comment: Can you show logs of `Run Unit Tests` step?

Comment: Make sure you the task `Run Unit Test` step create the test file `test-result.xml`, if you could not modify it, share the log in your question. I will help you check it.

Comment: @Józef Podlecki, Would you mind share some more info? So, we could help you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched **vmImage** to windows, mocha reporter to **mocha-junit-reporter** and now it runs fine.

I didn't bother checking other reporters after changing the image.

Here's the diff.

```yaml
- job: build_web
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'

...

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testRunTitle: 'Mocha Tests'
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
```

```json
"scripts": {
    "test:pipeline": "mocha --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./test-result.xml --timeout 60000 --require test-setup.js --recursive ./ClientApp/**/*.spec.ts*",
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "mocha": "6.2.0",
     "mocha-junit-reporter": "1.23.1",
  }
}
```